# Issue with PyPDF2 and decoding pdf file from S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3, pypdf

I am trying to get a pdf file stored in one of my S3 buckets in AWS, and get some of its metadata like number of pages, and file size. I successfully get the pdf file from the S3 bucket, getting this when calling print(obj)

```
s3.Object(bucket_name='somebucketname', key='somefilename.pdf')
```

When using PyPDF2.PdfFileReader() I try using the raw file, a UTF-8 decoded file, and a ISO-8859-1 decoded file. The ISO-8859-1 decoded file is the only one that doesn't raise an exception, but when trying to pass it into PdfFileReader as a parameter I get an error, and this traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s3_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    pdfFile = PdfFileReader(parse3)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1081, in __init__
    fileobj = open(stream, 'rb')
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

Am I using the wrong encoding type to decode this pdf file, or is it something else like the first argument of pdfFileReader has to be a file path? Is there an easier way to access an S3 pdf object's metadata without having to jump through hoops to get there?

Python Script

```
import boto3
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, itemname)
parse3 = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode("ISO-8859-1")
pdfFile = PdfReader(parse3)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's the overall strategy:

1. Let PyPDF2 handle the decoding

PyPDF2 will be much smarter at determining how to decode the file than you will be. PdfFileReader can read from a stream or a path to a file so can read the file from S3 and prepare it as a byte stream. Let PdfFileReader do the hard work.

2. Preparing the byte stream

To prepare the file stream as a byte stream you can use the BytesIO library.

Python 2:

```
from BytesIO import BytesIO
```

Python 3:

```
from io import BytesIO
```

For your code example:

```py
from io import BytesIO

import boto3
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader


s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, itemname)
fs = obj.get()["Body"].read()
reader = PdfReader(BytesIO(fs))
```

Comment: Hi @JBT Can you check this answer and mark correct if it answers your questions?

Comment: I had almost the exact problem and your solution worked.

Comment: Thanks, I used this to solve for reading pymupdf -> fitz.open(stream=fs, filetype='pdf')