# extract text from pdf File from S3 bucket python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-pdfreader

I have multiple format files in my AWS s3 bucket like pdf,doc,rtf,odt,png and I need to extract text from it.
I have managed to get the list of contents  with their path .now depending on the file type i will use different libraries to extract text from the file . since files can be in thousands i need to extract text directly from s3 instead of downloading.

```
filespath=['https://abc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/DocumentOnPATest', 'https://abc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/IndustryReport2019.pdf', 'https://abc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/receipt.png', 'https://abc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/sample.rtf', 'https://abc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/sample1.odt']

bucketname =abc
```

I tried something but its giving me error

```
for path in filespath:
    ext=pathlib.Path(path).suffix
    if ext=='.pdf':
       pdf_file=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(path)
       print(pdf_file.extractText())
```

but i am getting an error

```
  File "F:\Projects\FileExtractor\fileextracts3.py", line 28, in <module>
    pdf_file=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(path)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1081, in __init__
    fileobj = open(stream, 'rb')

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://abc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/IndustryReport2019.pdf
```

please help me with the lead. Thank you

Comment: "since files can be in thousands i need to extract text directly from s3 instead of downloading" -- you can not operate on data locally unless you download that data. This doesn't mean you have to write it to a file and it doesn't mean you have to keep it after finishing processing either.

Answer (score 0):

`PyPDF2` does not support reading from s3 directly. You'll need to download them first locally.

<strike>or you can try using [AWS Lambda functions][1] to process files directly from s3 buckets.</strike>

Comment: sorry but i didnt understand it .can u explain me in a simple terms . do i need to create a lambda function in my aws lambda if yes then how can it be applied on multiple files .@Krishna Chaurasia

Comment: Actually, based on the link in the answer, I think even with lambda functions, you'll have to download the files from s3 before processing it. I'll edit the answer to remove the second part.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the boto3 solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373967/issue-with-pypdf2-and-decoding-pdf-file-from-s3), provided by Justin Leto.  You would still need a way of reading/converting the file stream for each file type but the PDF answer is there.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, itemname)
fs = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```